# How to bind multiple (n) polygons to Bing Map controls

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I want the ability to bind a collection of LocationCollection instances to Bing Maps control in WP7 (Silverlight). I'm able to bind a single instance of a polygon using the following XAML:

```
<Microsoft_Phone_Controls_Maps:MapLayer.Children>

    <Microsoft_Phone_Controls_Maps:MapPolygon Locations="{Binding Polygon}"
                                                          Fill="{StaticResource PolygonFillBrush}"
                                                           Stroke="{StaticResource PolygonStrokeBrush}"
                                                           StrokeThickness="4"
                                                           Opacity="1">
    </Microsoft_Phone_Controls_Maps:MapPolygon>

</Microsoft_Phone_Controls_Maps:MapLayer.Children>
```

This has bound a single LocationCollection using the Polygon property on the ViewModel. I want to be able to bind an ObservableCollection to the MapLayer so I can draw as many polygons as is required.

I can do this in code (code-behind) but I would prefer to declare this in XAML, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a `MapItemsControl` (In this example, xmlns:maps = Microsoft_Phone_Controls_Maps)

```
<maps:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Polygons}">
    <maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <maps:MapPolygon Locations="{Binding Polygon}"
                             Fill="{StaticResource PolygonFillBrush}"
                             Stroke="{StaticResource PolygonStrokeBrush}"
                             StrokeThickness="4"
                             Opacity="1" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</maps:MapItemsControl>
```

Comment: I did this and in my case the `Polygon` property is an object of type `Geopath`. But it is throwing me an exception when trying to bind, with message `"The parameter is incorrect.\r\n"`